# How i can create new thread to do some task and stop the thread after the task finish

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

its seems to be a stupid question but I'm trying to create a task in a new thread, and after the task is finished the thread should exit without calling anything to stop it from main.

Here is an example:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        foo f1= new foo();
        Thread t= new Thread(f1);
        f1.doSomething();
    }
}
class foo extends Thread{

    void doSomething(){
        // download File for example
    }
}
```

if I implement the run method  like this :

```
class foo extends Thread{

    void doSomething(){
        // download File for example
    }
    void run(){
      doSomething();
    }
}
```

it is going to call doSomething() method forever.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

```
public class ThreadExample extends Thread {

     private void doSomething(){
          System.out.println("Inside : doSomething()");
     }  

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Inside : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        doSomething();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Inside : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        System.out.println("Creating thread...");
        Thread thread = new ThreadExample ();

        System.out.println("Starting thread...");
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

> One output:
>
> Inside : main
>   Creating thread...
>   Starting thread...
>   Inside : Thread-0
>   Inside : doSomething()

For further informations, check out this [Java Concurrency and Multithreading tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
 foo f1= new foo();
 Thread t= new Thread(f1);
 f1.doSomething();
```

This is not the away to start a thread. Basically you call thread.start() method to start the thread which will execute everything which is there in run method.

Please go through the tutorial first

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: yeah I know that,  but I wrote f1.doSomething(); to demonstrate what I need